# Google drive api web authentication for a specific account to view files

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-drive-api

I have a little question..

----*the structure is: lawyers-customers.*--------

**Every Customer**

-use an android app which upload photos(eg.: documents) into his drive.

-through app the photos shared with a specific google account's drive (eg.:justice@gmail.com)

**Every Lawyer**

-use a site(php,codeigniter) 

-in this site has an account where can find his customers.

Now my **question for the lawyers's site** 

->Is there a way to achieve the authorization automatically without lawyer interaction for justice@gmail.com in order to view a customer's photos;

Apologize for the length of question, but  my English isn't so good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there a way to achieve the **authorization automatically without lawyer interaction**"

Errr, no.

The whole point of authorization is that it is the lawyer interacting in some way to grant permission, in this case to the php app. Automatic authorization wouldn't make much sense would it.

The good news is that the lawyer only needs to grant the authorization once. The app records this fact by storing a refresh token, which it can use henceforth to access the lawyer's drive files.